# Render a vue property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to render a property in my component.

I have in the template:
        
`<v-flex v-for="c in components"> 
      <component :is="c.component" v-bind="c.prop"></component>
</v-flex>`

And in the script:

```
...
mounted(){
        this.components.push({, 
          component: "input", 
          prop: {type:"checkbox", v-text:"My CheckBox"}
        })
```

It works using any component or property. But the problem is when I'm trying to render the **v-text**. I think it is because of the -

How could I render successfully the v-text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, unquoted property names can only contain alphanumerics, `_` and `$`. So to include a `-` you need to quote it:

```js
{ "v-text": "My Checkbox" }
```

Double or single quotes will work, your choice.

Without the quotes I wouldn't even expect the code to parse/transpile, so I would have expected there to be a clear error message.

The next problem is that you can't use `v-bind` for `v-text`. They are two separate directives so what you're effectively doing here is:

```
v-bind:v-text="'My Checkbox'"
```

That will just be interpreted as a DOM attribute with no special meaning. If you inspect the DOM you'll see the `v-text` attribute, which wouldn't be there if it were being interpreted as a directive.

Instead you'll need a separate entry in your data:

```js
this.components.push({, 
  component: "input", 
  prop: {type:"checkbox"},
  text: "My CheckBox"
})
```

and then in your template:

```html
<component
  :is="c.component"
  v-bind="c.prop"
  v-text="c.text"
></component>
```

or:

```html
<component
  :is="c.component"
  v-bind="c.prop"
>
  {{ c.text }}
</component>
```

All of that said, an `input` element cannot have any content anyway, so trying to use `v-text` would be meaningless in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think "v-" starting names are reserved, you might have to change v-text to text and then handle it inside the component.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Special-Attributes

```html
mounted(){
        this.components.push({, 
          component: "input", 
          prop: {type:"checkbox", text:"My CheckBox"}
        })
```